# Meeting with the decision maker after the final interview

Tags: job-search, tenure-track

My second interview for a tenure track position in US was completed last Monday and I was the first interviewee. Today the chair of the department has contacted me to arrange a meeting saying that he wants to discuss about my application. Also, he wants to know my phone number.

Do you have any idea concerning this meeting? What should I prepare for? Thank you.

Comment: "Last Monday" and "today" are descriptions of a timeline that don't age well...

Answer (score 2):

There is too little information here to know why the chair wants to talk to you. The fact is somewhat promising - if the school was not interested they would not follow up in this way.

Comment: That is why I address the question. Should it be another campus interview?

Comment: @ttguest Who knows. You can speculate all day, but short of actually knowing anything, it is only that: speculation.